# Android Market Doesn't Show My New Version

Tags: android, upgrade, google-play, apk

I fixed a bug in my Android app, and uploaded the new APK to the market (I signed it with the same private key as the first version).  My versionCode and versionName are both different, and the "Android Market listings" section of https://market.android.com/publish/Home shows my new version number (1.0.1).  However, when I search for my app in the market, it still shows my original version number (1.0) and when I download it, the market version doesn't have my fix.

On the 'APK Files' section of the 'Edit Application' page, my new version is 'Active', and my old version is shown as 'Previously Active'.

The developer console says that my app is up to date, but the market doesn't show it.  I published 2 hours ago.  Did I miss any steps in the upgrade process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have mentioned everything, i can say "No you are not missing anything" and i have also marked the same thing that **android market takes time (few minutes/hours/days) to show updates of application**. So don't worry, if you have uploaded the updates of application it will appear soon.

Answer (score 0):

i also face same problem when i upload next version my APK File.
if u change any thing in your manifest file related `uses-permission` or `uses-feature` it might be issue. other than u active latest version APK and than go Product Details Tab. In that u accept `Consent` . in Consent there are 2 check box u accept both check box and again save the APK. now within 1 hour your apk is Active and u can see in android market

Comment: I did miss that at first, but I've checked those consent boxes. Thanks!